# Maven repository with Voldemort jars

Tags: java, maven-2, voldemort

I'm looking for a public Maven repository that has the [Voldemort](http://project-voldemort.com/) libraries. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there isn't but here is a [description how to get them in your local repo](http://newitfarmer.com/java/75).

This cqn be easily extended to install them to your nexus or artifacory if you have one (and if you call typing 3-line command lines easy).

Comment: Ok thanks. The thing is, I need to reference the Voldemort jars in case I want to include a Voldemort sample in Preon (preon.codehaus.org), and I don't want everybody checking out Preon to go through the same pain.

Comment: I found voldemort/voldemort and voldemort/voldemort-contrib on clojars. 

<repository>
  <id>clojars.org</id>
  <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
</repository>